# Display JS variable in html textbox

Tags: javascript, html

For some reason clicking the button will not but the variable in the textbox, I'm not getting any syntax errors in my compiler so I think it's a logic error. THanks in advance

JS:

```
var testvar = 5
$('.teambtn').click(function() {
document.getElementById('team').text = (testvar);
});
```

html:

```
<textarea id=team cols="50" rows="10">
Your Team Will be here:
</textarea>


            <button type="button" id=teambtn class="btn">Export</button>
```

Comment: I also tried without the parentheses around 'testvar' so that's not the problem

Answer (score 1):

I think you're almost there. You just need to remove the brackets from test var and instead of replacing the .text property, you need to replace the .value property

```
document.getElementById('team').value = testvar;
```

Check out this link because I think it accomplishes what you want, http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/form/add-text.html

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is below .

$('.teambtn')

try to use $('#teambtn') .

Because you declared it is an id . But the selector indicates to class .

If you do not want to change the .js code then you can add it as a class .

I hope this will helps you .

Answer (score 0):

Since you have used jQuery, below is sample usage:

```
var testvar = 5
$('#teambtn').click(function() {
   $('#team').val(testvar);//set the value of textarea
});
```

`teambtn` and `team` are ids given, so to fetch by id using `jQuery's` selector `#`

To get/set the value of `textarea` and `input` elements use `jQuery's` `$.val()`

**EDIT**

Problem with your code is that you are trying to set `text` property of `textarea`, which is not valid instead you must try using `value` attribute:

```
document.getElementById('team').value = testvar;
```